# How to have logarithmic bins in a Python histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

As far as I know the option Log=True in the histogram function only refers to the y-axis.

```
P.hist(d,bins=50,log=True,alpha=0.5,color='b',histtype='step')
```

I need the bins to be equally spaced in log10. Is there something that can do this?

Comment: You must divide the count in each bin by the bin width if you do so!

Answer (score 157, accepted):

use logspace() to create a geometric sequence, and pass it to bins parameter. And set the scale of xaxis to log scale.

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(size=10000)
pl.hist(data, bins=np.logspace(np.log10(0.1),np.log10(1.0), 50))
pl.gca().set_xscale("log")
pl.show()
```

[image]

Comment: note that `np.logspace(0.1,1.0,...)` will create a range from `10**0.1` to `10**1.0`, not from `0.1` to `1.0`

Comment: should be `np.logspace(np.log10(0.1),np.log10(1.0),50)`

Comment: See my answer for how to use bins='auto'

Comment: @AndreHolzner @OrangeSherbet One can use [`np.geomspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html) to specify endpoints directly.

Comment: Note that the photo doesn't match the code. The limits on the x-axis should be from 10**-1 to 10**0.

Answer (score 26):

The most direct way is to just compute the log10 of the limits, compute linearly spaced bins, and then convert back by raising to the power of 10, as below:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(size=10000)

MIN, MAX = .01, 10.0

pl.figure()
pl.hist(data, bins = 10 ** np.linspace(np.log10(MIN), np.log10(MAX), 50))
pl.gca().set_xscale("log")
pl.show()
```

[image: log10 spaced bins]

Answer (score 17):

The following code indicates how you can use `bins='auto'` with the log scale.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = 10**np.random.normal(size=500)

_, bins = np.histogram(np.log10(data + 1), bins='auto')
plt.hist(data, bins=10**bins);
plt.gca().set_xscale("log")
```

[image: chart]

Comment: why did you add "+1" (in np.log10(data + 1))? I see that it regularize the case of log(0), but does this not create proble mo represent with the binning the data <1?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what was stated, performing this on pandas dataframes works as well:

```
some_column_hist = dataframe['some_column'].plot(bins=np.logspace(-2, np.log10(max_value), 100), kind='hist', loglog=True, xlim=(0,max_value))
```

I would caution, that there may be an issue with normalizing the bins. Each bin is larger than the previous one, and therefore must be divided by it's size to normalize the frequencies before plotting, and it seems that neither my solution, nor HYRY's solution accounts for this.

Source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0412004.pdf