# Log x-axis for histogram

Tags: matplotlib, plot, histogram, axis

I'm trying to plot a histogram with a logarithmic x axis. The code I'm currently using is as follows

```py
plt.hist(data, bins=10 ** np.linspace(0, 1, 2, 3), normed=1) 
plt.xscale("log")
```

However, the x axis doesn't actually plot correctly! It just goes from `1` to `100`. Ideally I'd like to have tick marks for `1`, `10`, `100`, and `1000`. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a sample dataset.

Comment: my data was a list of radiation exposure amounts--let me find the list. data=[13.140,17.520,15.768,10.512,10.512,9.636,10.512,  9.636,11.388,7.884,7.008,7.008,9.636,11.388,7.884,7.88,16.644,42.924,17.520]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have logarithmic bins in a Python histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855710/how-to-have-logarithmic-bins-in-a-python-histogram)

Answer (score 29):

The following works.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = [1.2, 14, 150 ]
bins = 10**(np.arange(0,4))
print "bins: ", bins
plt.xscale('log')
plt.hist(data,bins=bins) 


plt.show()
```

In your code the probelm is the `bins` array. It has only two values, `[1, 10]`, while if you want tickmarks at `1,10,100,and 1000` you need to provide those numbers as `bins`.

Comment: Note this won't work with the `density` argument as it normalizes using distances and not logarithmic distances