# How to compress the space of the x-axis when using scale_x_log10()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
db %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = y_1+1)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..)), bins = 50, fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
  scale_x_log10() +
  theme_test()
```

results in this

[image]

I want no white space between bars.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't simply want to change the size of some bins and not others, but rather change where the tick marks go and "squish" the part near zero. As far as I know, the only solution (besides increasing your bin size by a lot) would be to use a different transformation rather than a log transformation.

This is certainly not a new problem, and many different axis transformations are used, for example, in displaying flow cytometry plots, as the measured intensities have huge ranges, but easy manipulation of the axes is key in analysis software. Some transformations can be quite complex to deal with negative values as well.

One easy option would be to apply a hyperbolic arcsine transformation (arcsinh), [this article](https://support.cytobank.org/hc/en-us/articles/206148057-About-the-Arcsinh-transform) gives some nice context.

These transformations tend to squish the values close to zero, with values becoming more and more linear the farther you go out. I'm sure there are other transformations out there with other behavior if you wish.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(cowplot)

set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
    x = sample(1000, 500, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Here's some example data where a log transformation creates some gaps in the left side of the data.

```r
data %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_histogram(
        aes(x = x, y = ..count../sum(..count..)),
        bins = 50,
        fill = "lightblue",
        color = "black"
    ) +
    theme_test() +
    scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

Instead of using a pre-built `scale_x` function on our plot, we can manually achieve this with a custom function, applying the arcsinh function to the data ourselves. Using the `breaks` and `labels` arguments of the `scale_x_continuous()` function, we can give the axis that nice look we're after.

Here are a few different plots with different values of the cofactor which will adjust the spacing of the decades along the x-axis:

```r
arcsinh <- function(x, cf) {
  asinh(x / cf)
}

cfs <- list(5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100)

plots <- lapply(cfs, \(cf) {
    data_plot <- data %>%
        dplyr::mutate(x_trans = arcsinh(x, cf))
    
    x_labels <- c(1, 10, 100, 1000)
    x_breaks <- arcsinh(x_labels, cf)
    
    ggplot(data_plot) +
        geom_histogram(
            aes(x = x_trans, y = ..count../sum(..count..)),
            bins = 50,
            fill = "lightblue",
            color = "black"
        ) +
        theme_test() +
        scale_x_continuous(
            breaks = x_breaks,
            labels = x_labels
        ) +
        labs(title = paste("cofactor =", cf)) +
        xlab("x")
})

cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = plots, nrow = 2, align = "hv")
```

[image]

I'd recommend trying different types of transformations as well as bin sizes to get what you're after for your own data.

Comment: How is it possible that numpy can do easily it but ggplot does not?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855710/how-to-have-logarithmic-bins-in-a-python-histogram

I do not understand if the arcsin is strictly necessary to squeeze logarithmic bins.